# Slim Framework status code 404

Tags: php, htaccess, http-request, http-headers, slim

Ao fazer requisições obtenho o seguinte erro.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com.br/api. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Meu `.htaccess` está assim: http://pastebin.com/HqMQM5xU

Quando eu não estou dentro do meu dominio funciona.
Então deduso que seja `.htaccess`

Comment: No log de acesso obtenho o seguinte.
10.0.0.30 - - [11/Jul/2016:11:15:36 -0300] "OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1" 404 522

Comment: isso é um problema de CORS, como não trabalho com o framework vou me abster de montar uma resposta